# Kong Rewrite Url Path on Interaction

Tags: kong

I have a route in kong **/app** that is supported by a nginx service

That nginx service is a simple webpage with a simple link that when clicked takes you to a /click-me route

```html
<a href = "/click-me" > click me </a>
```

How do I make it so that when clicked, and without rewriting my html code, the Kong Gateway proxies that request to **/app/click-me** instead of /click-me? /click-me will return an error in kong as that route is not set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use kong plugins like route transformer advanced(enterprise) or request transformer advanced(enterprise) or url rewrite
(third party) applied to a route, and rewrite the route url to the original endpoint of the upstream service.

Comment: It would be really helpful if someone could show how to use one of these plugins with the example above.